# Making items bigger in the item frame

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-resource-packs

[image]Hello guys I've made a model for the bowl to look like basket and it's definitely working but now I need help making the items bigger when I put them in the item frame. My plan goes like that:
I place a block

I put frame on it

I put bowl in the item frame

and then make it look like the block is in basket.

That's image of my stuck situation..

Comment: Can you give us the custom model json file?

Answer (score 1):

To make items bigger in an item frame, the scale value for a *fixed position display* needs to be set. The maximum visible value for this scale factor is 4.

To make the display appear even larger, you can scale the model up yourself and reduce the other displays' scale values. I wouldn't recommend doing this due to a difficulty in accuracy.

https://minecraft.wiki/w/Model#Block_models

> scale: Specifies the scale of the model according to the scheme [x,
> y, z]. If the value is greater than 4, it is displayed as 4.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a texture to the item or edit an existing one.
When you see an item in the item frame it shows the items texture and to make the item bigger you just have to make a bigger texture.

Comment: "You have to add a texture to the item" what does that mean? How do you make the item bigger?